# Typescript DragEvent syntax

Tags: angular, typescript, drag, tsc

I have an angular application where I need to explicitly fire a drag event. I am using AOT - ngc and rollup.

```js
    let event1 = new DragEvent();
event1.initDragEvent('dragstart', true, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event1]);
```

The code compiles fine and the page loads in the browser. But at runtime, I get this error:

> Failed to construct 'DragEvent': 1 argument required, but only 0 present.

Now, I change the code to look like this:

```js
let event1 = new DragEvent('dragstart');
this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event1]);
```

Now, the compiler throws and error saying:

> Expected 0 arguments, but got 1.

How do I overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer was rather simple.

```
let event1 = new Event('dragstart');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using,

```
this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [new DragEvent('dragstart', true, true)]);
```

Comment: This didn't work. Error ==> Expected 0 arguments, but got 3.

Comment: Try initializing event using: `object.createEvent (event1 );` 
rather than using : `new DragEvent();`

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. What is object - the native element? What should event1 be instantiated to? Can you please provide a couple of lines of code?

Comment: `event1 = new DragEvent();

event1 .createEvent (DragEvent);

event1 .initDragEvent ('dragstart', true, true, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);

this._renderer.invokeElementMethod(this._elementRef.nativeElement, 'dispatchEvent', [event1]);`

Comment: This didn't work. Same error as the original fish. I think if I use the right type file, it would help. Would you know which defintely typed component contains definition for drag event?